# Regular expression too big error for cucumber pickle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, pickle

I am getting below error when i am trying to run my cucumber features.

```
    Using the default profile...
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.5, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.6
Strategy is : truncation and ORM is active_record
regular expression too big: /^((?:(?:)|(?:(?:a|an|another|the|that) )?(?:(?:(?:(?:first|last|(?:\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th))) )?(?:project[_ ]search[_ ]query|activity|workspace[_ ]permission|person[_ ]import|onboarding[_ ]setting|folder|project[_ ]membership[_ ]search[_ ]query|post[_ ]attachment|activity[_ ]started[_ ]event|comment|answer[_ ]search[_ ]query|onboarding[_ ]email[_ ]template|onboarding[_ ]contact[_ ]role|open[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|onboarding[_ ]role[_ ]setting|email[_ ]template|onboarding[_ ]action|announcement|import|radio[_ ]list[_ ]question|workspace[_ ]theme|instant[_ ]workspace[_ ]email[_ ]message|activity[_ ]added[_ ]event|onboarding[_ ]request[_ ]audit|radio[_ ]list[_ ]answer|create[_ ]issue[_ ]event|word[_ ]cloud|person[_ ]community[_ ]role|display[_ ]image[_ ]question|onboarding[_ ]status|activity[_ ]reassigned[_ ]event|report[_ ]summary[_ ]field|workspace[_ ]poll|onboarding[_ ]permission|workspace[_ ]right|onboarding[_ ]type|send[_ ]message[_ ]activity|activity[_ ]suspended[_ ]event|organization|right|activity[_ ]deleted[_ ]event|activity[_ ]reopened[_ ]event|true[_ ]false[_ ]question|issue|activity[_ ]execution[_ ]completed[_ ]event|activity[_ ]reactivated[_ ]event|community|activity[_ ]completed[_ ]event|issue[_ ]import|freshness[_ ]email[_ ]template|task[_ ]execution|db[_ ]file|default[_ ]project[_ ]permission|alertq[_ ]recipient|project[_ ]deleted[_ ]event|report[_ ]group|onboarding[_ ]contact|multiple[_ ]choice[_ ]answer|file[_ ]upload[_ ]question|web[_ ]form[_ ]activity|pending[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|participant[_ ]comment[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|membership|question[_ ]group|project[_ ]membership|issue[_ ]notification|survey|activity[_ ]execution[_ ]search[_ ]query|report[_ ]format|workspace[_ ]person[_ ]preference|onboarding[_ ]right|answer|onboarding[_ ]approval[_ ]group|line[_ ]item|project[_ ]added[_ ]event|onboarding[_ ]email[_ ]field|true[_ ]false[_ ]answer|issue[_ ]saved[_ ]search|attachment|file[_ ]attachment|report|project[_ ]right|script|organizational[_ ]role|line[_ ]item[_ ]saved[_ ]search|custom[_ ]field[_ ]permission|resolve[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|multiple[_ ]choice[_ ]survey[_ ]question|yes[_ ]no[_ ]question|workspace[_ ]event|custom[_ ]field[_ ]right|form|onboarding[_ ]approval[_ ]level|mediator[_ ]comment[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|uploaded[_ ]txt[_ ]file|onboarding[_ ]reminder[_ ]history|text[_ ]field[_ ]answer|comment[_ ]issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|number[_ ]question|uploaded[_ ]gif[_ ]file|file[_ ]upload[_ ]custom[_ ]field|form[_ ]response|file[_ ]download[_ ]question|person[_ ]search[_ ]query|item[_ ]with[_ ]document[_ ]url|permission|activity[_ ]reminded[_ ]of[_ ]event|calendar[_ ]event[_ ]role|organization[_ ]profile[_ ]question|date[_ ]answer|project[_ ]permission|app[_ ]email[_ ]message|question[_ ]group[_ ]permission|workspace|number[_ ]answer|question[_ ]group[_ ]right|organizational[_ ]membership[_ ]search[_ ]query|alert[_ ]query[_ ]email[_ ]message|open[_ ]issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|report[_ ]sort[_ ]order|issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|issue[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]count|alert[_ ]query|create[_ ]issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|role|onboarding[_ ]question|yes[_ ]no[_ ]answer|text[_ ]field[_ ]question|organization[_ ]type|drop[_ ]list[_ ]answer|organizational[_ ]membership|search[_ ]query|onboarding[_ ]workflow|project[_ ]event|tag|onboarding[_ ]request[_ ]history|topic|uploaded[_ ]image|activity[_ ]execution|community[_ ]membership|issue[_ ]field[_ ]authorization|calendar[_ ]event|activity[_ ]reminder[_ ]event|community[_ ]role|welcome[_ ]workspace[_ ]email[_ ]message|survey[_ ]answer|video|onboarding[_ ]company|report[_ ]type|issue[_ ]type|daily[_ ]workspace[_ ]email[_ ]message|saved[_ ]search|address|freshness|onboarding[_ ]process|item|content[_ ]library[_ ]file|drop[_ ]list[_ ]question|onboarding[_ ]contact[_ ]audit|community[_ ]permission|survey[_ ]question|item[_ ]with[_ ]document|custom[_ ]field[_ ]group|workspace[_ ]search[_ ]query|issue[_ ]event|question[_ ]choice|onboarding[_ ]custom[_ ]audit|report[_ ]option|workspace[_ ]membership|email[_ ]message|display[_ ]text[_ ]question|integer[_ ]survey[_ ]answer|organization[_ ]import|sso[_ ]source|activity[_ ]search[_ ]query|post|onboarding[_ ]approval[_ ]mapping|date[_ ]question|resolve[_ ]issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|organization[_ ]search[_ ]query|community[_ ]footer[_ ]pref|question|onboarding[_ ]reason|onboarding[_ ]requester|community[_ ]right|workspace[_ ]email[_ ]message|file[_ ]download[_ ]answer|project|person|workspace[_ ]item[_ ]preference|workspace[_ ]role|audit[_ ]record[_ ]field|text[_ ]area[_ ]answer|person[_ ]profile[_ ]question|project[_ ]role|onboarding[_ ]membership|multiple[_ ]choice[_ ]survey[_ ]question[_ ]choice|report[_ ]field|audit[_ ]record|manager[_ ]comment[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|multiple[_ ]choice[_ ]question|onboarding[_ ]request|address[_ ]type|file[_ ]upload[_ ]answer|undeliverable[_ ]issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|uploaded[_ ]file|text[_ ]area[_ ]question|pending[_ ]issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|file[_ ]alert|report[_ ]summary[_ ]function|onboarding[_ ]role|onboarding[_ ]pre[_ ]approval[_ ]group))|(?:(?:project[_ ]search[_ ]query|activity|workspace[_ ]permission|person[_ ]import|onboarding[_ ]setting|folder|project[_ ]membership[_ ]search[_ ]query|post[_ ]attachment|activity[_ ]started[_ ]event|comment|answer[_ ]search[_ ]query|onboarding[_ ]email[_ ]template|onboarding[_ ]contact[_ ]role|open[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|onboarding[_ ]role[_ ]setting|email[_ ]template|onboarding[_ ]action|announcement|import|radio[_ ]list[_ ]question|workspace[_ ]theme|instant[_ ]workspace[_ ]email[_ ]message|activity[_ ]added[_ ]event|onboarding[_ ]request[_ ]audit|radio[_ ]list[_ ]answer|create[_ ]issue[_ ]event|word[_ ]cloud|person[_ ]community[_ ]role|display[_ ]image[_ ]question|onboarding[_ ]status|activity[_ ]reassigned[_ ]event|report[_ ]summary[_ ]field|workspace[_ ]poll|onboarding[_ ]permission|workspace[_ ]right|onboarding[_ ]type|send[_ ]message[_ ]activity|activity[_ ]suspended[_ ]event|organization|right|activity[_ ]deleted[_ ]event|activity[_ ]reopened[_ ]event|true[_ ]false[_ ]question|issue|activity[_ ]execution[_ ]completed[_ ]event|activity[_ ]reactivated[_ ]event|community|activity[_ ]completed[_ ]event|issue[_ ]import|freshness[_ ]email[_ ]template|task[_ ]execution|db[_ ]file|default[_ ]project[_ ]permission|alertq[_ ]recipient|project[_ ]deleted[_ ]event|report[_ ]group|onboarding[_ ]contact|multiple[_ ]choice[_ ]answer|file[_ ]upload[_ ]question|web[_ ]form[_ ]activity|pending[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|participant[_ ]comment[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|membership|question[_ ]group|project[_ ]membership|issue[_ ]notification|survey|activity[_ ]execution[_ ]search[_ ]query|report[_ ]format|workspace[_ ]person[_ ]preference|onboarding[_ ]right|answer|onboarding[_ ]approval[_ ]group|line[_ ]item|project[_ ]added[_ ]event|onboarding[_ ]email[_ ]field|true[_ ]false[_ ]answer|issue[_ ]saved[_ ]search|attachment|file[_ ]attachment|report|project[_ ]right|script|organizational[_ ]role|line[_ ]item[_ ]saved[_ ]search|custom[_ ]field[_ ]permission|resolve[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|multiple[_ ]choice[_ ]survey[_ ]question|yes[_ ]no[_ ]question|workspace[_ ]event|custom[_ ]field[_ ]right|form|onboarding[_ ]approval[_ ]level|mediator[_ ]comment[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]event|uploaded[_ ]txt[_ ]file|onboarding[_ ]reminder[_ ]history|text[_ ]field[_ ]answer|comment[_ ]issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|number[_ ]question|uploaded[_ ]gif[_ ]file|file[_ ]upload[_ ]custom[_ ]field|form[_ ]response|file[_ ]download[_ ]question|person[_ ]search[_ ]query|item[_ ]with[_ ]document[_ ]url|permission|activity[_ ]reminded[_ ]of[_ ]event|calendar[_ ]event[_ ]role|organization[_ ]profile[_ ]question|date[_ ]answer|project[_ ]permission|app[_ ]email[_ ]message|question[_ ]group[_ ]permission|workspace|number[_ ]answer|question[_ ]group[_ ]right|organizational[_ ]membership[_ ]search[_ ]query|alert[_ ]query[_ ]email[_ ]message|open[_ ]issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|report[_ ]sort[_ ]order|issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|issue[_ ]line[_ ]item[_ ]count|alert[_ ]query|create[_ ]issue[_ ]email[_ ]message|role|onboarding[_ ]question|yes[_ ]no[_ ]answer|text[_ ]field[_ ]question|organi (RegexpError)
/home/rollstream/Programming/rollstream/community_service/features/step_definitions/line_item_steps.rb:154
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `polyglot_original_require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
/home/rollstream/Programming/rollstream/community_service/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:124:in `load_code_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:85:in `load_code_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:77:in `load_code_files'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:76:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:76:in `load_code_files'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:51:in `execute!'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/bin/cucumber:8
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/cucumber:19
```

Comment: The regular expression that you are using is too long. It is about 8k.
What are you trying to achieve and what does your feature look like.

Comment: a issue type exists with name: "Shipping", abbreviation: "ship" is the pickle statement it is matching
the error showing up like that but regular expression is small

Comment: pickle gem crashes if number of models in rails app crosses the reggular expression limit.

Comment: I hit this one too.  For those who are saying to move the logic from the regex around, the regex is generated by pickle automatically.  Anybody found a fix for it yet?

Answer (score 1):

Had a very similar problem, and currently there is no perfect solution for this but there are some workarounds:

http://groups.google.com/group/pickle-cucumber/browse_thread/thread/c6be23c6247fa0dd